# Conditional table cell font color content formatting in javascript not working for 0.xx/-0.xx numbers but works fine for 1.xx/-1.xx?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

Trying to create a ranking system, using table to display figures, have managed to conditionally change cell backgrounds based on cell contents, and am now trying to change font color based on cell content of other cells.

Table below works with existing script but does not recognise 0.01 as being >0 or -0.01 as being <0

Also be good to have one script and not 3 or 4 as per example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>colored rating scale</title>
    <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"
    
  ></script>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css"-->

    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"-->


  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
table {
  width: 60em;
}

#name {
  width: 20%;
}

#symbol {
  width: 5%;
}

#thisrank {
  width: 10%;
}

#lastrank {
  width: 10%;
}

#change {
  width: 10%;
}
#marketcap {
  width: 15%;
}

#price {
  width: 15%;
}

#weekpc {
  width: 5%;
  
}
#monthpc {
  width: 5%;
}

#yearpc {
  width: 5%;
}

th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.1em 0;
}

th:nth-child(even),
td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: center;
}

.up {
  background-color: #9f0;
  /*color:#9f0;*/
}

.nochange {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.down {
  background-color: #f30;
}

.fdown {
  color: #f30;
}

.fup {
  color: #9f0;
}

.fnochange {
  color: #000;
}

   
  </style>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  

<b>This table now works for conditional background color BUT, <br> 
1. <u>font color</u> of "weekpc" , "monthpc" and "yearpc" should be red/green/no-color 
according to whether the contents are negative/positive/no-change in percentages.<br>
2. All fonts should be Arial.</b>
<br>
<table align="center">
  <col id="name" />
  <col id="symbol" />
  <col id="thisrank" />
  <col id="lastrank" />
  <col id="change" />
  <col id="marketcap" />
  <col id="price" />
  <col id="weekpc" />
  <col id="monthpc" />
  <col id="yearpc" />
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th colspan="3">Rank</th>
      <th>Market Cap.</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Week %</th>
      <th>Month %</th>
      <th>Year %</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>   
    <tr>
     <td align="left">      </td>
     <td align="left">      </td>
     <td align="center"><b> This Week   </b></td>
     <td align="center"><b> Last Week   </b></td>
     <td align="center"><b> Change  </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
     <td align="right"><b>      </b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  ABC Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  ABC </td>
     <td align="center">    1   </td>
     <td align="center">    1   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> 0   </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> -0.99%  </td>
     <td align="right"> 1.115%  </td>
     <td align="right">   2.12%  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  DEF Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  DEF </td>
     <td align="center">    2   </td>
     <td align="center">    3   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> -1  </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> -10.05% </td>
     <td align="right"> -15.33% </td>
     <td align="right"> -0.6%   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td align="left">  GHI Corp.   </td>
     <td align="left">  GHI </td>
     <td align="center">    3   </td>
     <td align="center">    2   </td>
     <td align="center"><b> 1   </b></td>
     <td align="right"> $686,270,744    </td>
     <td align="right"> $770.58 </td>
     <td align="right"> 0.01%   </td>
     <td align="right"> -15%    </td>
     <td align="right"> 25% </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>  


<!-- This works for background-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
  //get td text
    var change = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text().trim());
    console.log(change)
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (change < 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('down')
    } else if (change > 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('up')
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(4)").addClass('nochange')
    }

  });
});
</script>

<!-- TEST  weekpc font color conditional, Not working for any 0.xx/-0.xx number ??
Be nice to have one script for all 3 columns!!  (7,8&9)    -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
  //get td text
    var weekpc = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(7)").text().trim());
    console.log(weekpc)
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (weekpc < 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(7)").addClass('fdown')
    } else if (weekpc > 0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(7)").addClass('fup')
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(7)").addClass('fnochange')
    }

  });
});
</script>

<!-- TEST  monthpc font color conditional. Not working for any 0.xx/-0.xx number ??  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
  //get td text
    var monthpc = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(8)").text().trim());
    console.log(monthpc)
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (monthpc < 0.00) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(8)").addClass('fdown')
    } else if (monthpc > 0.00) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(8)").addClass('fup')
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(8)").addClass('fnochange')
    }

  });
});
</script>

<!-- TEST  yearpc font color conditional. Not working for any 0.xx number ??  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('tbody > tr').each(function(index) {
  //get td text
    var yearpc = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(9)").text().trim());
    console.log(yearpc)
    //depending on condtion add class..
    if (yearpc < .0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(9)").addClass('fdown')
    } else if (yearpc > .0) {
      $(this).find("td:eq(9)").addClass('fup')
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:eq(9)").addClass('fnochange')
    }

  });
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] - can you [edit] so only the relevant code is included?

Comment: It *looks like* the relevant code is `var yearpc = parseInt($(this).find("td:eq(9)").text().trim());`  if `td:eq(9).text()` = `0.1` then that will explain your problem - `parseInt("0.1")===0)`   if you want decimals, don't use `parseInt` but use `parseFloat`

Comment: Was just about to say what @freedomn-m said, yes. This sounds to me like an issue caused by using int where a float is necessary. An integer will chop off the decimal places if given a floating point number, making any number between -1 and 1 round to 0 every time. But please do edit with only the minimal reproducible example so we can help better.